# pkill vpn terminates all my script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vpn, openvpn

I am working with a Dialog GUI.

`./sdvpn.sh` is the code for the GUI main menu, shown below.

`./killvpn.sh` is a script containing only one command, `sudo pkill vpn`

`./region.sh` is a Dialog menu allowing to specify the country you desire your VPN to connect to.

When **I want to kill any active OpenVPN connections**, I select option 2 on the menu below:

```
`#!/bin/bash

#Main Menu

HEIGHT=15
WIDTH=40
CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
BACKTITLE="VPN"
TITLE="Main Menu"
MENU="Choose an Option: "

OPTIONS=(1 "VPN Menu"
         2 "Kill Active VPN")

CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                --title "$TITLE" \
                --menu "$MENU" \
                $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

clear
case $CHOICE in
        1)
        cd ~/VPN/gui
        ./region.sh
        ;;
        2)
        cd ~/VPN/scripts
        ./killvpn.sh
        cd ~/VPN
        ./sdvpn.sh
        ;;

 esac`
```

**This code for Option 2 is supposed to achieve the following:**

- lead to my Scripts directory
- Exectute `sudo pkill vpn`
- Return to the main folder where my main menu.sh is kept
- Run the main menu, taking the process full circle.

**The Problem**

It will not return to the main menu, and I have no way to troubleshoot this. The same methodology worked perfectly when rolled out on Kali Linux 2018.2.

When I execute `sudo pkill vpn` or my `killvpn.sh` file, it simply kills the VPN connections as expected. However when running the same script from the Dialog GUI, I receive a message which says "Terminated."

I have tried rerouting the `killvpn.sh` to activate the Dialog GUI as part of its script, but the same problem occured.
I have then tried, with both `sudo pkill vpn` and `killvpn.sh` to include the sleep command, as I was simply returned to the terminal, and believed this was a process it could execute in order to continue running the code, but this failed too.

I am now unable to kill the VPN from my GUI, and I would like to know if there was a way I can either remove the "Terminated." message, or a way to accomplish my task. As a bonus ball, I would be grateful if someone could explain to me under what conditions will `pkill vpn` display this message, so I can avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I found that using the command
`sudo killall openvpn` was both a more effective way of terminating OpenVPN Connections, and also avoided the dialog I got with `sudo pkill vpn` allowing me to return to the dialog menu without any issues.